# ffmpeg create screenshots full of artefacts and completly illegible

Tags: ffmpeg, screenshot

I am using ffmpeg to create 15 screenshots from video with simple command

```
ffmpeg -ss 10:00 -y -i 'video.mp4' -f mjpeg -vframes 1 -an 'image.jpg'
```

command is executed 15x in row with different -ss time. But sometimes, completly randomly, images - all 15, even each of them is created by own process, are basicaly generated full of artefacts and completly illegible:
[image]

I believe is not problem with video, as they are almost always different - codecs, bitrate, lenght, quality, resolution, etc. I was trying search similar problem, but only same problem i found was when images was created from real-time stream over UDP (problem with UDP transfer protocol), which is not my case as ffmpeg and videos are installed and stored on same HDD (centos OS). Otuput from ffmpeg command is also without any error. I am also unable reproduce this behavior, when i run process for screenshots again, all screenshots are created properly. My only suspicion is server load, screenshots are created on encoding server which have average load around 50% on CPU: [image]
Is it possible that when the CPU is fully loaded, ffmpeg can create broken images?